# Rails 3.2 Mountable App locale getting duplicated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am seeing a scenario where my locale parameter is getting duplicated once I step into a mountable app. My app looks like so:

```
#routes.rb

resources :blogs

scope "(:locale)" do
  mount Auth::Engine => '/auth'
end
```

If I am at a blogs page and look at an auth link it looks like this `/en-us/auth/signout` which works well, but as soon as I load into any page rendered by the mountable app, for example the profile page `/en-us/auth/myprofile'`, the sign out link now looks like `/en-us/auth/signout?locale=en-us`

I don't want the querystring getting cluttered, what is causing the app to correctly set the locale parameter and then duplicate it in the querystring?

Answer (score 1):

my bet is that your application controller has something like:

```
def set_locale
  # code here
end

def default_url_options
  # code here
end
```

Since your engine controller inherits from application controller, set_locale may be triggered twice.

Potential Solution: Check if the code is in an engine, then don't trigger locale setting.

This can be done with: `self.controller_path().split("/").first == engine_name`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was setting the default url options on the controller (by redefining `default_url_options` or by using `self.default_url_options=`).

The solution was to use `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options =` instead.